# How to stop an event in powershell if No is pressed in a confirmation message box

Tags: powershell, datagridview

I have a DataGridView filled with rows with the ability to select and delete a row using Delete key.
There is a confirmation message box popping up when Delete is pressed, asking Yes or No to proceed with the deletion.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = '800,800'
$Form.text                       = "Form"
$Form.TopMost                    = $false

$DataGridView1                   = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$DataGridView1.BackColor         = "#f7f7f7"
$DataGridView1.width             = 771
$DataGridView1.height            = 716
$DataGridView1.Anchor            = 'top,right,bottom,left'
$DataGridView1.location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,68)

$import                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$import.text                     = "import"
$import.width                    = 60
$import.height                   = 30
$import.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(25,22)
$import.Font                     = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$save                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$save.text                       = "save"
$save.width                      = 60
$save.height                     = 30
$save.location                   = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(125,22)
$save.Font                       = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($DataGridView1,$import,$save))


$import.Add_Click({ importXML })
$save.Add_Click({ saveXML })
$DataGridView1.Add_UserDeletingRow({ message })

$DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = 16
Function importXML(){
    $xml_input = Get-FileName
    $ds = New-Object System.Data.Dataset
    $ds.ReadXml($xml_input)
    $DataGridView1.DataSource = $ds.Tables[0]
}
Function message(){
    $msgBoxInput = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Proceed with the deletion?","Delete confirmation","YesNo","Question")
        if ($msgBoxInput -eq "YES" ) 
        {
            [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("The selected row will be deleted")
        }
        else
        {
            #stop the deletion
        }
}
Function saveXML(){
    $xml_output = Save-FileName
    $DataGridView1.DataSource.writexml($xml_output)
}

[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Everything is working perfectly except after `else`. I have no idea on how to abort the deletion event.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Probaly not best practice but have you tried `exit` / `break`?

Comment: Set a $GLOBAL: variable value and in the deleteion code check the value of that variable.

Comment: @Paxz it doesn't work. I got an error message "Unhandled exception has occurred in your application..."

Comment: @EBGreen I have no deletion code. All relevant code is the one in my original post. Everything else is GUI related only. I don't understand your suggestion about $GLOBAL variable. Could you explain?

Comment: what about `else {return}`

Comment: Try using `return` in the else.

Comment: `return` just accept the deletion :-/

Comment: I've just edited my original question. Now there is the full code there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the MSDN examples, we see them do this in c# by setting `e` as a reference to the current event, and then setting `e.Cancel` equal to true, which allows us [to cancel the event as covered here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.userdeletingrow(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)  The syntax looks like this:

```
private void DataGridView1_UserDeletingRow(object sender,
DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e){
  e.Cancel = true; //Cancel the event
}
```

Well, in PowerShell if we try to add an event handler in this way, we'll get errors, because event handler methods generally only allow us to specify one overload which is the scriptblock to run on the event.

It turns out that it's deceptively easy to reference the current event, fortunately!  To cancel the Deletion, simply add this to your `add_UserDeletingRow()` scriptblock.

```
else
        {
            #stop the deletion
            $PSItem.Cancel=$true
        }
```

You could also use the `$_` current item syntax as well, which would look like

```
else
        {
            #stop the deletion
            $_.Cancel=$true
        }
```

Any time you're adding an event handler and need to refer to the event itself with PowerShell( and there are LOTs of Events like this, [look at all of them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx#Events) for `DataGridView` alone!) you'll use `$_` or `$PSItem`.  So in those examples from MSDN, if you see them referencing the current event with `e` or something similar, just substitute `$_` or `$PSItem` and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Awesome! It works flawlessly... It's hard to find information about Powershell on MSDN. Everything there is only for C#, C++ and VB, but never for Powershell. Frustrating. Anyway, I'm looking forward to post some harder questions :-) Thanks.